# changing `tr` style whenever an `input` was focused?

Tags: html, css, input, background-color

I have the following html :

```
<table id="TableNewUser" runat="server" width="50%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1"
border="0">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">
        New User
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="50%" align="right">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUsername" runat="server" Style="direction: rtl;" MaxLength="25"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td align="left" width="50%">
        UserName
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPass" runat="server" MaxLength="25"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        Password :
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="ButtonSubmitClick" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I wanna change the `tr` style whenever the text-boxes are focused.
I've used below CSS code but it doesn't work.

```
input[type="text"]:focus tr
{
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Could you please guide me?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Seems like a valid question.

Comment: Upvoted since this seems like a valid question, and no-one gave a reason for it to be downvoted.

Comment: Just happened to look at my rep and I didn't remember downvoting recently, I must have misclicked or hit tab and space or something. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mr. Dissappointment stated, you must use JavaScript (or jquery) to achieve what you want.

I coded a very simple HTML page to exemplify:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeTrStyle()
{
document.getElementById("trId").style.background = "red";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr id="trId">
        <td>
            <input type="text" onfocus="changeTrStyle()"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you focus the textbox, the *tr* background will become red.

**Note:** Tested on Safari and Chrome.