# Affect table row CSS on link :focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

How does one affect a `<tr>`'s styling when an `<a>` tag inside gets focused?

Here's the table HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href"#" tabindex="1" accesskey="e">edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I hit 'Tab' the link is in fact selected. I am also able to affect the link's styling like so:

```
a:focus {
    background: #CCC;
}
```

I can't wrap the `<tr>` in an `<a>` tag because I have multiple links on one table row.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: do you want to affect the entire row? how many td in your tr tag?

Comment: Can you use `jQuery`?

Comment: @Godinall, yes, the entire row, there are 9 `td`s in each `tr`,  of which are links.

Comment: @gmo yes I have some experience with jQuery

Comment: you'll have to use a bit of javascript or jquery then, there is no parent selector at the moment, not even in css3

Comment: @proPhet, sorry, I see your comment too late yesterday and you have already a few valid answers... I will suggest the use of [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) as well or [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) `jQuery functions`. Any way, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fiddle works for FOCUS... in FF and Chrome.
The OP request was not for mouseenter...

IE has jQuery focus issues... see [JQuery focus() is not focusing in IE but it is in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996577/jquery-focus-is-not-focusing-in-ie-but-it-is-in-chrome) for more info on that.

FF / Chrome fiddle for FOCUS:
http://jsfiddle.net/pmg45/2/

HTML:

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <a class="link" href"#" tabindex="1" accesskey="e">edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a class="link" href"#" tabindex="1" accesskey="e">edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
a { display:block; cursor:pointer; }
.red{ background:red; }
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.link').on('focus', function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass('red');  
    });
    $('.link').on('focusout', function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('red');   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS cannot affect parent elements. Only sibling and child elements are supported.

You will need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Try this SO post: [changing `tr` style whenever an `input` was focused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669492/changing-tr-style-whenever-an-input-was-focused)

(Reprinted from that page)
Use a `getElementByID` script and target the row as needed:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeTrStyle()
{
document.getElementById("trId").style.background = "red";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr id="trId">
        <td>
            <input type="text" onfocus="changeTrStyle()"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works but only for the first `tr` element in the `table`. PS the `tr`s are being generated dynamically

Comment: Updated fiddle from the other comment to address the focus... as opposed to `mouseenter` `mouseleave`  
http://jsfiddle.net/pmg45/2/

Comment: @ Minder Saini... Sorry can't comment yet. OP states: "How does one affect a `<tr>'s` styling when an `<a>` tag inside gets focused?"  Your solution was elegant and 99%.. .but it wasn't a hover question it was a focus. your solution didn't change elements when the tab key was used... only a mouse event. The focus uses the tab.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with jquery, check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Mohinder/pmg45/

CSS

```
a { display:block; cursor:pointer; }
    .red{ background:red; }
```

HTML

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="link" href"#" tabindex="1" accesskey="e">edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="link" href"#" tabindex="1" accesskey="e">edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.link').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass('red');  
    });
    $('.link').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('red');   
    });
});
```

Comment: @Phlume why focus and focusout, why not mouseenter and mouseleave ?

Comment: It was working fine the way it was earlier so I have changed it to first version, sorry @Phlume your one wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

In css, you cannot affect the parent element when it's child getting affected.

you have to use `jquery` to affect that parent...

In jquery you can use hover function to change it's parent

for example :

```
  $('a').hover(function(){
  $(this).parent().css({"color":"red"});
  });
```

the above coding will change the color of immediate parent of the link when it is hovering